# Find $E[Y_5\vert Y_1 = y_1]$ where $Y_t = \cos(tW)$ and $W$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

> Find $E[Y_5\vert Y_1 = y_1]$ where $Y_t = \cos(tW)$ and $W$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$

So I think this is as follows:

Given the definitions of $Y_t$ and $W$ in the title, and 
Since we know $Y_1=y_1$, we know $W=w$.

That is,
$$
w = \cos^{-1}{(1\cdot y_1)} =\cos^{-1}{(y_1)} 
$$
Thus, we by knowing $Y_1=y_1$ we know $W=w$, and thus
$$
E[Y_5\vert Y= y_1] = E[\cos{(5\cdot W)}\vert y_1] = \cos{(5\cdot w)}
=\cos{(5\cdot \cos^{-1}{(y_1)})}
$$

I am wondering if this simplifies further, or if I made a mistake? It just seems a bit messy to me (although I guess it is easy numerically)

Comment: A common convention is to [use upper case letters for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics), which is [also usually the case for stochastic processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Notation). As such and since you have not clarified further, it is hard to "guess" what is random and what is deterministic in your question. Is $w$ supposed to be a random variable? I also think you might benefit from some parenthesis' around the arguments of your cosine functions. "$\cos t$" is of course clear but "$\cos 5\cdot w$" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Therkel You are completely right. I tried to make everything more explicit, and I specified the distribution of $W$, since I had forgotten to do that.

Comment: Hint: $$\cos(5W)=16(\cos W)^5-20(\cos W)^3+5\cos W$$

Comment: Very nice. Your arguments seem correct now.

Comment: @Did, that answers my question. However, I was not aware of that formula. Is there a general version, and if so could you cite a source or provide a website (I'm not having luck with a Google search for things like "cosine properties" and "cosine of a product", although perhaps my Google-ing skills are low).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every real number $w$, $$\cos(5w)=16(\cos w)^5-20(\cos w)^3+5\cos w$$
hence $$Y_5=\cos(5W)=16(\cos W)^5-20(\cos W)^3+5\cos W=16Y_1^5-20Y_1^3+5Y_1$$ This shows that $Y_5$ is $\sigma(Y_1)$-measurable and that $$E(Y_5\mid Y_1)=Y_5=16Y_1^5-20Y_1^3+5Y_1$$ which implies that, for every real number $y_1$, $$E(Y_5\mid Y_1=y_1)=16y_1^5-20y_1^3+5y_1$$ This result holds for every distribution of $W$.

Comment: The back and forth between the inverse of cosine and the cosine is not useful and should be replaced by the identity between random variables $$Y_5=16Y_1^5-20Y_1^3+5Y_1$$ which shows that $Y_5$ is $Y_1$ measurable and that $$E(Y_5\mid Y_1)=Y_5=16Y_1^5-20Y_1^3+5Y_1$$

Comment: @Did. Woah. I did not see that at all. I feel like I just had my eyes opened.

Thanks, Did. You have been super helpful. I appreciate it.